# Dapper mapping MySql BIT(1) data type to ulong instead of boolean

Tags: .net, mysql, dapper

Please has anyone come across the above situation with Dapper and MySQL.  In all my tables in MySQL (5.1), where the data type is BIT(1) or BIT, Dapper simply return such field as ulong (UInt64).  I am using MySql.Data.MySqlClient and I have no such issue with EF which is what I am trying to convert from.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: my gut is telling me this is an issue with the mysql driver ... can you repro the problem with straight ado.net ... eg select the column and get the value ... look at the type?

Comment: The simple workaround is to add a shadow property or field to your type

Comment: @Sam Saffron: I could not reproduce it with straight ADO.NET and also I tried PetaPoco, it did not have the same problem. I tried to  investigate further, MySql actually returns 0 for false and 1 for true, why that shows up as ulong still beats me. Can you expand on what you mean by shadow property and how I can use it solve this.

Comment: @Sam Saffron: I have tried selecting only one bool field from the database, and I could see it stops on the direct cast (T)val in the GetStructDeserializer. A 0 or 1 (as ulong) cannot be directly casted to bool. A similar issue arise from the GetClassDeserializer as well. Would a special handling such as you did for char and char? incur performance penalty?

Comment: I have a similar problem with SQLite and INTEGER. A primary key is an INTEGER in the SQLite database (auto increment only works on INTEGER, for some reason), but my POCO has int. I expected it to cast down to int without problems (NHibernate does!). I really couldn't understand what in the Dapper code generates the casting (and why this generated cast fails), and I can't find any good documentation explaining what the generated IL really does. @sam-saffron - Adding a shadow property is hackish and I'd love an actual solution!

Comment: @SamSaffron I got this problem too. I worked around it but it caused my ORM to suffer as well. In my case `MySqlDataReader r` leads r[i] on `BIT` to be a UInt64. Its kind of annoying. I need to patch that up in my ORM now. But as for dapper can i workaround it bc i actually dont need to read the value. Its only used for my where statements. I just avoid * for that table and its simply 3 col (+2 for id and flag)

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, the type `Boolean` is mapped to `Tinyint(1)` with MySQL. Perhaps you will have to cast it to `Boolean` (0=false/1=true), `Convert.toBoolean(UInt64)` may help you (see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33f2zy48.aspx).

@Christian Droulers: The behaviour of SQLite is similar.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do the casting in your sql query ?

```
cast(myField using TINYINT(1)) as myField
```

Not sure abot the type here, but that's the way I do when my db type doesn't match my object's.